# Is it possible write a cookie with the current url using Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

A third party application I am working with normally allows the user to bookmark pages anywhere on the site.   Once logged in the user will be redirected to the original page requested.   Unfortunately through a commissioned single sign on customization this functionality gets lost.   That is to say if you use a bookmark to access a specific page in the product (or get an email or follow an external link), if you are not already signed in you go to a log in page and then get returned to the main application page instead of the page requested.

If I can set a cookie with the original URL requested I can then use that information through JavaScript to change the location upon landing on the home page.

Let's say the home page is /app/index.jsp - If I could get a cookie to remember any URL but this one - I could restore the functionality that the user goes to the requested page after they log in.   Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting problem... I sometimes open several bookmarks at once (in my browser, middle click on a bookmark folder). I can't think of a workaround that works reliably in such scenario. Whatever, wouldn't it be easier to generate the cookie with Java, right before redirecting to the SSO login page?

Comment: I do not have access to the Java code.   I can get the vendors hosting facility to make Apache configuration changes and I can add JavaScript to the product easily - but I do not have the ability to write Java for it unless we brought it in house.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to this myself...
Using mod_rewrite I could key on the initial request by looking for the JSESSIONID cookie.   The folowing when placed within my servers virtualhost section achieved my goal.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/adm/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/index\.jsp$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*JSESSIONID=.*$
RewriteRule . - [co=appURI:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}:.mydomain.com]
```

Note: I added some filters above for pages I did not want to set the cookie for.   I use JavaScript to detect, unset the cookie, and redirect within the application to achieve my goal.

```
var appURI = getCookie("appURI");
if (typeof(appURI) != "undefined" && appURI != null && appURI != "") {
  mydomain.console.log("Found URI from SSO relocating to: " + appURI);
  setCookie("appURI", "", -1, "/", "mydomain.com");
  document.location.href = appURI;
}
```

Note that "setCookie" and "mydomain.console.log" above are proprietary but simple functions that do the obvious actions based on their names.